# |Java| Spades Game unexpected output on print statements

Tags: java

Recently, I've tried to create a Spades game in java. Ive managed to make the card and the deck class, but whenever I try to print out either a random card or a deck of cards, sans 2 of diamonds and clubs, I have an unexpected result. Here is my code:

Main class

```
package com.star.spades;

import com.star.cards.Card;
import com.star.cards.Deck;

public class Spades {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        Card randCard = deck.drawCard();

        System.out.println(deck);
        System.out.println(randCard);

    }

}
```

Card Class:

```
package com.star.cards;

public class Card 
{
    private int suit;
    private int value;

    private String [] suits = {"Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades", "Hearts", };
    private String [] values = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
                                "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    private String [] joker = {"Joker"};
    private String [] jokerValue = {"Little", "Big"};


    public Card(int suit, int value)
    {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String outputCard()
    {
        return value + "of" + suit;
    }

    public String outputJoker()
    {
        return value + " " + suit;
    }
```

Deck Class:

```
package com.star.cards;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {
    private int numberOfSuits = 4;
    private int numberOfValues = 52;
    private int jokers = 1;
    private int jokerSize = 2;

    private ArrayList<Card> deck;
    private ArrayList <Card> hands;

    public Deck()
    {
        deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSuits; i++)
            for(int j =0; j < numberOfValues; j++)
            {
                deck.add(new Card(i, j));
            }

        for(int i = 0; i < jokerSize; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < jokers; j++)
            {
                deck.add(new Card(i, j));
            }
        deck.remove(1);
        deck.remove(13);
    }

    //draws random card and removes it from deck.
    public Card drawCard()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int index = rand.nextInt(deck.size());
        return deck.remove(index);
    }


    //deals 13 random cards to the player
    public ArrayList<Card> dealCards()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            hands.add(drawCard());
        }

        return hands;
    }
}
```

and here is the result:

```
com.star.cards.Deck@143b9a5f
com.star.cards.Card@5513dd59
```

Could you let me know what I need to do to print out my deck and cards on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to print objects directly. By default, the toString() method, which is called by print, will print out the *reference* to your object. So that weird thing you are getting is actually code for the location in memory where your object is stored. If you want to print out something else (for example some properties of the class) you must override the toString() method in your object's class.

Comment: I did what you suggested. The output was a pair of random numbers, one for the value of the card and one for the value of the suit. I think i want to see if I can figure out the issue on my. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. By overriding toString() you can make the output whatever you want! You have a lot of power now and can format the output to suit your needs. @JibrilBurleigh

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement/override the `toString` method in your classes. You will find many examples online for how to do that. For your `Card` class, a simple version could look like this:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Card[suit=" + suits[suit] + ",value=" + values[value] + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either implement `toString` in your classes or call a specific method that returns a string representation. Currently when you do `System.out.println(card)` it prints card's instance `toString` but since you didn't implement it yourself, it uses the parent class that did implement it - `Object`. Since `Object` has no information about your specific object, it prints a generic name and reference location address string.

If you choose to implement `toString`, all you have to do is add the method to your classes, for instance in `Card` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return value + " " + suit;
}
```

And the same for your `Deck` class (not sure what you want to print there). Your `Spades` class is left untouched.